# Jekyll is putting spaces around my id names making them useless

Tags: jekyll, liquid, static-site

Jeykll is outputting catergory_name and tag_name variables with spaces around it, which is destroying my IDs used with the variable.

Has anyone seen this before?

```
<a class="link" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/categories/#{{category_name}}">{{category_name}}</a>
```

The output on website with a category name of pizza. Notice the category name (pizza) in the URL has a space before and after.

```
<a class="link" href="/categories/# pizza ">pizza</a>
```

Comment: Any chance this code base is open sourced so others can recreate the problem locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce the leading whitespace in my test environment so the best I can do is suggest a workaround.

You can try to trim all leading and trailing whitespaces in your `{{category_name}}` Liquid variable with `strip` [1].

```
{{ category_name | strip }}
```

[1] https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/strip/

Comment: Hey @Kin. Your solution worked perfectly. Thank you so much for that. I appreciate it. Sorry for the delay. I was away for a week.

Comment: Hi @davidlower8, glad the solution works for you.  If this answer is helpful to you, please see if any of these actions are applicable for my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sure I have marked the question answered (I wasn’t aware I could do that so nice to know). I also upvoted it but it won’t show as I’m under level 15. Thanks.